# "There has been an error processing your request" while moving to server

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, exception, error-log

I have created my magento website on my localhost with magento 1.9.x. With windows 7 and xaamp server.
URL was

> `127.0.0.1/demo`

Database name was

> demo

Now I want to move it from localhost to my server.. Steps I took to do it are

> I have put my Magento in directory `example.com/MyMagentoProject`
>
> Clear the cache manually
>
> Made changes in `app/etc/local.xml`
>
> database Name changed to magentoproject

Now my website giving me below error

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 192262631357

Error log number changes everytime when i refresh page... i have refreshed tons of time each time the error code is diffrent

what is the problem?

**(NOTE) if it helps**
when I was exporting my database from `localhost/phpmyadmin` it gave me error

> Warning: a form on this page has more than 1000 fields. on submission,
>   some of the fields might be ignored, due to PHP's max_input_vars
>   configuration.

so I have changed `max_input_vars = 1000` to `max_input_vars = 10000` and exported my database. but while importing database to server it took around 10 mints to upload my database but no error

Comment: go to root/errors/local.xml.sample to rename it as local.xml then reload the page you will get error in front end